# requiring same instance of module in another router nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

in server.js

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const getSqlInstance = () => {
    return sql
}

module.exports = {
    getSqlInstance
}
```

in database.js

```
const sql = require('../../server').getSqlInstance();
```

why does this throw `require(...).getSqlInstance is not a function` error? How do I resolve this?

folder structure

```
root
  -- routes
    --api
      --database.js
  --server.js


TypeError: require(...).getSqlInstance is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jiho.Choi.ROOT_MILLIMAN\Desktop\BoosterADS\excelvcs\routes\api\database.js:4:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jiho.Choi.ROOT_MILLIMAN\Desktop\BoosterADS\excelvcs\server.js:38:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Comment: Is this all of your server.js? Please show a full version.

Comment: Full version is about 400 lines so I cannot post it but that is all that is being used here @MustansirZia

Comment: Alright, is this your only `module.exports` line in the whole file?

Comment: yes it's the only one @MustansirZia

Comment: can you please show me your folder structure for database.js and server.js?

Comment: @MustansirZia updated

Comment: Sounds like a circular dependency (A.js requires B.js which requires A.js, etc...)

Comment: Does your server.js require your database.js too?

Comment: @MustansirZia no should it?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Post all of your server.js code on https://jsfiddle.net/ and let me see. Promise this will be the last thing. :)